# Use viewer.js plugin in symfony2

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, twig

I need help to install http://viewerjs.org plugin to view pfd files in Symfony2. That plugin contains css/js files and images with its own folder structure.

This is what I have done:

1. Copy all js files to AcmeBundle/Resources/public/js
2. Copy all css files to AcmeBundle/Resources/public/css
3. Copy images folder (which originally was into css folder in the plugin) to AcmeBundle/Resources/public/images
4. Change url(images/xxxx) functions of css files to url(../images/xxxx)
5. Install assets: php app/console assets:install web
6. Include the following code to the view I want to use viewer.js.

   ```
   <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/acme/css/viewer.css') }}" />
   <script src= "{{ asset('bundles/acme/js/PluginLoader.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src= "{{ asset('bundles/acme/js/viewer.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <iframe id="viewer" src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/js/viewer.js') }}/#../uploads/1.pdf" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
   ```

"1.pdf" file is in /web/uploads/ folder.

When I load the view, I get in the place of the iframe element:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /bundles/acme/js/viewer.js/ was not found on this
>   server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn`t how Viewer.JS works.

You can't display `bundles/acme/js/viewer.js/` as source of iframe becouse index.html in  Viewer.js is file that should be displayed as source.

1. Download [Viewer.js](http://viewerjs.org/Viewer.js-0.2.1.zip) And extract it to `AcmeBundle/Resources/public/` so you should have `AcmeBundle/Resources/public/Viewer.js/` dir with all files from zip
2. run `php app/console assets:install web`
3. Put in your twig view:

   ```
   <iframe id="viewer" src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/Viewer.js/index.html') }}#{{ asset('uploads/1.pdf') }}" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
   ```

You don't need to put scripts and styles because they are load in `Viewer.js/index.html` that is viewer

Comment: How do you get this to work in `prod` environment?

I did exactly what you said above, Sync files to server, install assets and clear cache. Still get the 404 error on the page use the asset view helper.

Comment: @thinkwinwin you probably have to run `app/console assets:install --env="prod"` You can read more about it on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#f-other-things